# Python Threads. Serial Port. KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port, keyboard-events

I'm implementing a multithreaded program where one of the threads reads from a serial port. I'm having trouble when trying to end the program with KeyboardInterrupt. For now I just have the main thread and the one that reads from the serial port. The code looks like this:

```
import threading
import time

def reader(name, port, run_event):
    while run_event.is_set():
        port.read(1)
        #Process data...............

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_event = threading.Event()
    run_event.set()
    port=serial.Serial(port=args.serialPort,baudrate=921600)
    port.flush()
    port.flushInput()
    t1 = threading.Thread(target = timed_output, args = ("Reader",port,run_event))

    t1.start()

    try:
        while 1:
            time.sleep(.1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Bye Bye"
        run_event.clear()
        t1.join()
        port.close()
        print "threads successfully closed"
```

Sometimes everything works fine but other times it does not. Those are some of the logs.

Why is this one not caught by the try-except block?

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "bbbDAQ.py", line 147, in <module>
    time.sleep(0.1)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Two interrupts where the first one takes us out of the try-expect block and then another while executing the print statement?

```
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "bbbDAQ.py", line 149, in <module>
    print 'Bye Bye'
KeyboardInterrupt
```

At this point I am really confused. Can someone explain what happens there and what am I missing.

-----------Edit_1----------------

Ive  changed the try-except block with this:

```
   def signal_handler(signal, frame):
            print 'Bye Bye'
            run_event.clear()
            t1.join()
            port.close()
            sys.exit(0)

    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT,signal_handler)

    while 1:
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

Most of the times the program exits as expected when ctrl-c is hit, but other times im getting this log:

```
^CBye Bye
Bye Bye
Exception SystemExit: 0 in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
```

Is the exception fired twice, how could this be posible?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436502/closing-all-threads-with-a-keyboard-interrupt